# Python pivoting with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Assuming I have the following DataFrame:

| ClassID | Name | Result_Str | Result_Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | TA | Clark |  |
| 456 | TA | Boris |  |
| 456 | Tony | >87 |  |
| 123 | Sam | <45 |  |
| 456 | Anna |  | 89 |
| 456 | Theo |  | 67 |

I want to be able to pivot to something like this where the *values containing >,<* are put into similar columns as is the case for **Result_Num** :

```
|ClassID| TA  |Anna|Tony|Sam|Theo|
|-------|-----|----|----|---|----|
|123    |Clark|    |    |<45|    |
|456    |Boris|89  |>87 |   |67  |
```

I know with **pandas** the df.pivot allows us to do this

```
df.pivot(index="ClassID", columns="Name",values="Result_Str")
df.pivot(index="ClassID", columns="Name",values="Result_Num")
```

But can **values** be made conditional based on whether `Result_Num` or `Result_Str` is defined/not equal to ""

Thanks,

Comment: The previous post had some issues when posting output table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prepare your dataframe before pivot. First, (1) create a boolean mask to find values which are not in the right column and move them. Then, (2A) split your dataframe in 2 sub dataframes: one for `Result_Str` column and another one for `Result_Num` column and (2B) pivot them. Finally, (3) merge your 2 dataframes on `ClassID` column:

```
# (1)
m = df['Result_Str'].str[0].isin(['<', '>'])
df.loc[m, 'Result_Num'], df.loc[m, 'Result_Str'] = df.loc[m, 'Result_Str'], np.nan

# (2A)
df1 = df.loc[df['Result_Str'].notna()].drop(columns='Result_Num')
df2 = df.loc[df['Result_Num'].notna()].drop(columns='Result_Str')

# (2B)
df1 = df1.pivot(index='ClassID', columns='Name', values='Result_Str')
df2 = df2.pivot(index='ClassID', columns='Name', values='Result_Num')

# (3)
out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ClassID').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

Output result:

```
>>> out
   ClassID     TA  Anna  Sam  Theo Tony
0      123  Clark   NaN  <45   NaN  NaN
1      456  Boris  89.0  NaN  67.0  >87
```

Comment: @editi. I fixed my answer. Can you kindly check it, please?

Comment: Yep it worked. Thanks!